# How to find second highest value from created loop from outputs from loop in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, nested-function

Beginning R programmer here and I want to find the most compatible person with a single person in the data frame. Compatibility is based on algorithms which assign points to certain values in the data frame.
I have a data frame called kewl.d00dz and it looks like this:

```
name  dream.name birth.state birth.month birth.date major
1   stephen       butch          CO         oct         11  ELEC
2     clark     richard          VA         jan         19  BUAD
3   anthony          bo          NJ         mar         26  BUAD
4      jack     kordell          VA         jul         27  BUAD
5      eric      adrian          ND         jun         17  GEOG
6     tyler     anthony          VA         apr         12  CPSC
7    olivia    isabella          VA         may         29  MATH
8      brad      harvey          HI         aug         21  BUAD
9    hannah     charlie          VA         aug         28  PSYC
10     will      ronald          VA         may         11  BUAD
11     noor         ani          CA         apr         14  BUAD
12 victoria   elizabeth          VA         jan         11  MATH
13 morgan c      lauren          FL         jun         15  BUAD
14 morgan w   elizabeth          VA         feb         21  ARTS
15   helena      helena          VA         apr         26  BIOL
16    amber amber leigh          VA         dec          6  PSCI
17     ekta        kate          VA         apr         14  ARTH
18 caroline     georgia          DC         jun         20  BUAD
19     anna        abby          VA         sep         21  BUAD
20     nate       julio          VA         sep          5  ECON
21  jessica    jeanette          VA         oct          7  BUAD
22   shaina      skylar          VA         sep          2  BUAD
23     ruth        lucy          VA         jan          4  CPSC
24   sohyun    caroline      Seoul          nov         16  PSYC
25    aaron         don          VA         sep          1  ECON
26     alex        axel          VA         sep          6  BIOL
       cell num.bills num.states
1      none         5         41
2     apple         8         14
3     apple         4         14
4     apple        19         10
5     apple         6         19
6   samsung         1         10
7     apple         3          8
8     apple         1         18
9     apple         2         16
10    apple         5         20
11    apple         3         19
12    apple         5         17
13    apple         3         15
14    apple         4         24
15  android         0         18
16    apple         1         12
17    apple         1         19
18    apple         0         22
19    apple         0         27
20  samsung         4         32
21  samsung         5         11
22    apple         0         15
23    apple         7         30
24    apple        10         10
25 motorola         8         18
26      htc         3         20
```

I need to find the most compatible person with whatever person I input into my function which is this:

```
    source("compatibility.R")
find.most.compatible<-function(x){
  a<-which(kewl.d00dz$name==x)
  x<-as.list(kewl.d00dz[a,])
  pts<-list()
  namez<-list()
  for (i in 1:nrow(kewl.d00dz)){
    y<-as.list(kewl.d00dz[i,])
    pts[i]<-compatibility(x,y)
    namez[i]<-kewl.d00dz[i,"name"]
    names(pts)<-namez
  }
  n<-length(pts)
  (which(pts == sort(pts,partial=n-1)[n-1]))
}
```

**I want it to return the second highest value to me, because if it returns the first the person will be most compatible with themselves. However it gives me this error message:**

```
    > find.most.compatible("stephen")
02727312231332325212224261723292219149302611312321
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic
```

Here is the function I am calling within the previously mentioned function
 which I do not want to change the code for:

```
compatibility<-function(x,y){
  #start point bag
  com.points<-0

  #number of bills compatibility points
  com.points<-com.points +(10-abs(as.integer(x[["num.bills"]] - y[["num.bills"]]))) 

  #different number of states compatibility points
  diff.states<-abs(as.integer(x[["num.states"]]-y[["num.states"]]))
  cat(diff.states)
  if(diff.states<5){
    com.points<-com.points+5
  } else if(diff.states<10){
    com.points<com.points+3
  } else {
    com.points<-com.points
  }
  #birth month compatibility points 
  if(x[["birth.month"]]== "dec"||x[["birth.month"]]== "jan"||x[["birth.month"]]== "feb"){
    season1<-"winter"
  } else if(x[["birth.month"]]== "mar"|| x[["birth.month"]]== "apr" || x[["birth.month"]]== "may"){
    season1<-"spring"
  } else if(x[["birth.month"]]== "jun"||x[["birth.month"]]== "jul"||x[["birth.month"]]== "aug"){
    season1<-"summer"
  } else {
    season1<-"fall"
  }

  if(y[["birth.month"]]== "dec" || y[["birth.month"]]== "jan" || y[["birth.month"]] == "feb"){
    season2<-"winter"
  } else if(y[["birth.month"]]== "mar"||y[["birth.month"]]== "apr"||y[["birth.month"]]== "may"){
    season2<-"spring"
  } else if(y[["birth.month"]]== "jun"||y[["birth.month"]]== "jul"||y[["birth.month"]]== "aug"){
    season2<-"summer"
  } else {
    season2<-"fall"
  }
   if (x[["birth.month"]] == y[["birth.month"]]){
     com.points<-com.points + 3
   } else if(season1==season2){
     com.points<-com.points + 1
   } else {
     com.points<-com.points
   }
  #birth state compatibility points
  if (x[["birth.state"]]==y[["birth.state"]]){
    com.points<-com.points + 1
    } else {
      com.points<-com.points
    }
  #major compatibility points
  if (x[["major"]]==y[["major"]]){
    com.points<-com.points + 4
  } else {
    com.points<-com.points
  }

  #cellular provider compatibility points
  if(x[["cell"]] == y[["cell"]]){
    com.points<-com.points + 2
  } else {
    com.points<-com.points
  }    
return(com.points)
}
```

Can someone please troubleshoot my code without using any special functions like apply,subset, etc?

Only ones allow are which.max and the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried the whole of your code, but I can see you'd need to modify your loop to something like this -- otherwise your function will return at the first iteration.

I commented out the names(pts) line b/c this could also go outside of your loop once all the items are in.

```
pts <- list() # if you actually want a list. You could also do c() for a vector

for (i in 1:nrow(kewl.d00dz)) {
  y <- as.list(kewl.d00dz[i,])
  pts[i] <- compatibility(x,y)
  # names(pts) <- sprintf(kewl.d00dz[i,"name"],1:length(pts))
}

return(pts)
```